# Can I see my active diplomatic deals in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

When making deals with AI I'm having a hard time assessing if I'm already trading for the resource or not. Is there a way I can see my currently active deals or deal history?

If not, is there a way I can see which resources I am currently importing?

Answer (score 2):

In the top/top left there is a tab called **reports**. Select that and in there you can see what items you are currently trading out and getting in - under the **current deals** tab. It's the same place you can see yields, units etc.

Here's a mod to enhance it if you really care as well. https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/unit-report-screen.25396/

Answer (score 1):

This is now slightly different in Civ 6 - New Frontier Pass (possibly in earlier expansions/updates). To view Diplomatic Deals, click the List of Reports button in the upper right, select Yields, then scroll to bottom to see your current deals.